# Markov Chain Monte Carlo thermolization time estimation (not by eye)

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo

For a given MCMC algorithm, there are two important time(=step) scale.

1. $\tau_{thermolization}$ also known as burn-in time, intialization time.
2. $\tau_{indenpendent}$ the time scale to make $X_i$ and $X_{i+\tau_{indenpendent}}$  independent from each other

$\tau_{indenpendent}$ can be extract from the auto-correlaton function of certain random variable $$C(t):=\langle X_i X_{i+t}\rangle -\langle X_i \rangle^2 \sim e^{-t/\tau_{indenpendent}}$$

For  $\tau_{thermolization}$, I don't see any explicit definition of it. Usually, I would plot a curve of $X_i$ , and then truncate at a location where the series looks "steady".

My goal is to write a program, which gives me estimation of $\tau_{thermolization}$ and $\tau_{indenpendent}$ before a major Monte Carlo simulation.

So I need an expression or algorithm for $\tau_{thermolization}$ , not by eye judgement.

Comment: What's your definition of the thermalization time? Doesn't it depend on your initial distribution? In the extreme case where you sample the initial state from the equilibrium distribution, the thermalization time is zero. For a less extreme case, if you simulate a ferromagnet in the disordered phase, with low magnetization, thermalization will be quicker if you choose the initial state by letting each spin independently point up or down with equal probability than if you start out with all spins aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from the molecular simulation community, where MCMC is heavily used along with molecular dynamics, to sample complex configurations of interacting molecules, I agree that this aspect is often glossed over and left as a "rule of thumb". However I'm aware of at least one paper where an attempt has been made, by John Chodera, to tackle it objectively: https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2015/07/04/021659 which was also published in [*J Chem Theo Comp,* **12,** 1799 (2016)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.5b00784). The author also provides a piece of Python software to implement the calculation automatically. Maybe this is what you need.

I won't try to reproduce the mathematics here, but the basic idea seems to be to use the procedure for estimating statistical errors in correlated sequences of data - which involves estimating the correlation time (or the statistical inefficiency), the interval between effectively independent samples, as you mention in your question - and applying it to the interval $(t_0,t_{\text{max}})$ which covers the period between the (proposed) end of the equilibration period and the end of the whole dataset. This calculation behaves in a predictable way if the dataset is at equilibrium; the method systematically carries it out as a function of $t_0$, reducing it from an initial high value, and attempts to detect the value of $t_0$ at which deviations from this expected behaviour are seen.

Anyway, hopefully that paper will be helpful.